# Is there a way to define a Class in JS Array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can i define Class of objects that are stored in array? Similar to

```java
ArrayList<? extends E> array = new ArrayList<?>()
```

Im trying to do something like this:

```js
let myArray = new Array(SomeClass)
```

but it's only pushing a class as first object, funny my IDE shows me, that objects in this Array are of SomeClass [image: image that shows array type]

Comment: The `Array()` constructor doesn't know anything about Typescript type information. The parameter to the constructor is interpreted as something to put in the new array.

Comment: why not use `SomeClass[]`?

Comment: @Pointy 
I was actually using plane javascript in my Vue project, now im adding TypeScript support and i will check if everything is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Just add the type definition to the variable.

```
let myArray: SomeClass[] = [];
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvY8B2EALgE4Cuwh8x0AFAA6kBGIAlsNAGbzwBc0RxFngDmASmwBfANzSAULJDJC0RAE8AgsWJhVfBCnSQIAbQC60ALzQzU+Ws3bVAOgYQAFjTzIA7nCRoMCBoAInVg0VFbey0dF1J3Tx8-A0CQgCFwyNloxziEr199AKMQ1EzbWS5qGlwCZWRFaHgOFQ0Y1XEsWWhoWoh4RScQeGEaBuQnLngsiSA) for this